# redirect to mobile without using any server-side code?

Tags: android, iphone, html, mobile, smartphone

Is there any current way to redirect to the mobile version of a desktop site without having to add any scripts to the desktop version?

Comment: That was not an appropriate comment.

Answer (score 1):

The "right" way to detect mobile visitors is to check the value of the [User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) HTTP header on incoming requests. You would do this at the web server level or the application level.

Since web server and actual web site implementation will differ from customer to customer, you're not going to find a magic bullet solution for this.